# FIND_IN_SET and Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value error

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

this is a part of my query:

```
select * from tb_test where IF(_Tags,
             TAD.id IN (
                 SELECT T2.taggable_id as id FROM Tb_Taggables T2
                 WHERE T2.taggable_type = 'archives'
                 AND
                FIND_IN_SET(T2.tag_id,_Tags)
             )
        ,TRUE)
```

`_Tags` has a value like this: `'377,379'`.

my `Tb_Taggables` table:

```
CREATE TABLE Tb_Taggables (
    id            bigint UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT
        PRIMARY KEY,
    tag_id        bigint UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    taggable_id   bigint UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    taggable_type varchar(191)    NOT NULL,
    created_at    timestamp       NULL,
    updated_at    timestamp       NULL
)
    COLLATE = utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

but I got this error message:

```
[22007][1292] (conn=29800) Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: '377,379'
```

Comment: None of your uses of `_Tags` in that query should have generated that error. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=d6ca14d92039fb11bf2fd36faa8431ed

Comment: Sample data would be very helpful here.  Note that `FIND_IN_SET` appearing in MySQL code is usually a design or code smell.

Comment: `_Tags` is a string, right? Why is it the 1st argument of the function `if()`?

Comment: @forpas because I want to check it when `_Tags` isn't `NULL`;

_Tags is a `text`.

Comment: @S.M_Emamian why not simply write `IF (_Tags IS NOT NULL , ....)` Reason you are getting this truncated warning/error because `IF(..)` statement expects the first parameter to be a conditional expression resulting in a boolean. Since, `_Tags` is text, it tries to implicitly typecast it to a boolean and thus generating this warning

Comment: The 1st argument of IF() should be a boolean expression: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_if. The way you use `_Tags` makes this if() return always TRUE (unless `_Tags` starts with a numeric digit).

Comment: @forpas yes, I changed it to `IF(NOT ISNULL(_Tags)` and it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why use a conditional expression at all?

```
where (_Tags is null or
       TAD.id IN (SELECT T2.taggable_id as id
                  FROM Tb_Taggables T2
                  WHERE T2.taggable_type = 'archives' AND
                        FIND_IN_SET(T2.tag_id, _Tags)
                 )
      )
```

In general, conditional logic in a `where` clause (`case` or `if()`) just complicates the expressions.

Now that you have that fixed, you can work on fixing your data model.  You are storing multiple values in a column.  Here are *some* reasons why that is bad:

- Numbers should be stored using the correct type, which is not a string.
- Ids that connect tables should have properly declared foreign key relationships, which you cannot do.
- Databases in general have poor string processing functionality.
- Databases have a great data structure for storing lists.  It is called a *table* not a *string*.
- Dumping multiple values in a string precludes the use of indexes and partitions on that column, which affects scalability and performance.